# Subversion or subclipse - How do I get a list of checked out files?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Does anyone know any way from the command line or with subclipse that I can get the list of files I have checked out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Subclipse, you can just right-click on a project and go to Team > Synchronize with Repository and it will take you to the "Team Synchronizing" perspective and show a list of files that are different.

Comment: This only shows the changed files, right? The OP wants to have a complete list of all files that are checked out. Any other way in Eclipse to get this complete list?

Comment: Subversion does not have a real "check-out" concept.  You basically get all the files, make any changes you want, and then sync them back to the repository.  The list of changes are similar to a list of checkouts. There is the idea of a "lock" which is like a "reserved checkout" in other SCM systems.

Answer (score 1):

`svn st -v` seems appropriate, I think. Try `svn help st` for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want a list of files (without any other information) you could append the command that [glowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238938/subversion-or-subclipse-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-checked-out-files/3238958#3238958) gave with [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
svn status -v | sed 's/\s*\d*\s*\d*\s.*\s//'
```

It filters out the information in front of the files names (at least it does for me)

Explanation of the sed argument:

- The first \d* filters out the current checkout revision
- The second \d* filters out the current file revision
- The .* filters out the authors name

(The \s* filters out spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste the information from SVN console after you checked out the code. If you don't know where SVN console is: Go to view Console view and click the icon with arrow. Select SVN console. All the files you've checked out should be listed there.